# Application Advise: SSE vs. WebSockets

Tags: sockets, websocket, server, server-side

I'm writing an application in which users will be able to send money to each other. I've built out most of it, but now comes the most important part, managing transactions as they occur.

What I'd like to do upon a successful transaction is to send an update to the recipient. Right now, my thinking is to do this via SSE or WebSockets. For this particular app, it doesn't appear that I need bi-directional communication, since the response would only be sent to the recipient's instance which should be listening for a response from the server.

I might be answering my own question here, but I also wanted to factor in scale. If my app grows to a million users, for instance, which technology would best be able to handle the number of transactions being processed without failure?

I'm also a little unsure as to how to implement this for the case where there is a multiplicity of users, but I only want a particular user to receive the update.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there isn't much good reason to use SSE unless you are sending the exact same data to lots of people through a proxy server, which you are not.

Comment: @user253751 - So you're suggesting websocket is the way to go?

Comment: Unless you have a particular reason to use SSE